# bannerview did not receive any banner due to Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

while i testing my iphone iad app in ipod touch,iad not displaying and the following error had occurred.(bannerview did not receive any banner due to Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x192b70 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable) in simulator it's working. how can i solve this problem. plz help me..

Comment: This error is due to missing data in iAd server or due to improper configuration. Also check you internet speed.

Comment: iAds is only for United States only. If your device or simulator is detected as outside of US, then you won't receive ad in anyway.